# How to increase performance in the View Port?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, optimization

I have model that has 100 000 cubes forming a 2d grid from a birds-eye view. The cubes are very simple in geometry, but still, with 100-200k it's hard to perform some tasks around the viewport.

Are there some options to remove and increase the performance? I've already disabled ambient occlusion, but it's still sometimes slow. Any advice?

NOTE: I don't want to cut the grid into multiple meshes and separate it in different layers if possible.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify the scene? Go to *Scene header* --> *Simplify* and reduce the viewport subdivisions to 2 or 1.

Comment: Maybe change that specific object's maximum drawing mode to bounding box?

Comment: If those cubes share the same object then viewport should have good enough performance. So try joining them into one object if possible.

Comment: @MrZak the cubes were originally made from one cube using the Array modifier twice, so they do actually belong to the same parent object

Comment: Modifiers especially on quite high levels (I assume that if initial cube is only one and the result includes 100k faces then Arrays are set to repeat a lot) are quite resource hungry. Try applying modifiers or using [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html) for arraying.

Answer (score -1):

If your cubes have more than 8 verts then I suggest using a decimate modifier. But not applying it. It will reduce the polycount and you can just undo it for a final render by deleting the modifier.